# Equality of Seminorms in vector bundles

Tags: general-topology, vector-bundles, locally-convex-spaces

In this notes [Geometric Wave Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4706) by [Stefan Waldmann](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12482/stefan-waldmann)  at page 7 he has
Let $E \longrightarrow M$ be a vector bundle of rank $N$.  For a chart $(U, \psi)$ we consider a compact subset $K \subseteq U$ together with a basis  sections $e_{\alpha} \in \Gamma^{\infty}\left(\left.\boldsymbol{E}\right|_{\boldsymbol{U}}\right)$ such that for a section $s$ we have
$$
\left.s\right|_{U}=s^{\alpha} e_{\alpha}
$$
We define the seminorms
$$
\mathrm{p}_{U, \psi, K, \ell,\left\{e_{\alpha}\right\}}(s)=\sup _{\substack{x \in K \\|I| \leq \ell \\ \alpha=1, \ldots, N}}\left|\frac{\partial^{|I|} s^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{I}}(x)\right|
$$

then he has

for every compact subset $K \subseteq M$ we consider another seminorm
$$
\mathrm{p}_{K, \ell}(s)=\sup _{p \in K}\left\|\left.\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell} s\right|_p\right\|_h,
$$
where $\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell}$ is the symmetrized covariant derivative

The goal here is to proof that
$$
\mathrm{p}_{U, x, K, \ell,\left\{e_\alpha\right\}}(s) \leq c \max _{\ell^{\prime} \leq \ell} \mathrm{p}_{K, \ell^{\prime}}(s)\tag 0
$$
to do that he uses the fact that
$$
\left.\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell} s\right|_U=\mathrm{d} x^{i_1} \vee \cdots \vee \mathrm{d} x^{i_{\ell}} \otimes e_\alpha \frac{\partial^{\ell} s^\alpha}{\partial x^{i_1} \cdots \partial x^{x_{\ell}}}+\text { (lower order terms). }
\tag{**}$$

his argument at page 11 is

given a $\mathrm{p}_{U, \psi, K, \ell,\left\{e_\alpha\right\}}$ we see from $(* *)$ that we can estimate the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^{|J|} s_s^\alpha}{\partial x^J}$ with $|J| \leq \ell$ by norm of $\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell} s$ and norms of partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^{\mid J^{\prime}} \mid s^\alpha}{\partial x^{J^{\prime}}}$ for $\left|J^{\prime}\right|<\ell$.

I am not seeing why his argument is true.

how can we proof eq $(0)$  for  $l=1$
where  have $$\left.\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell} s\right|_U =\left[\partial_i s^a+\left(\Gamma_E\right)_{i b}^a s^b\right] d x^i \otimes e_a \tag 1$$?